# nginx return command returns https url without www

Tags: url, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to setup nginx to return https url for all http requests.
The problem is, that it returns https url without the www which results in invalid url.

Here is my config:

```
server {  
  listen 80;  server_name my_server;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {  
   listen   443;  
   ssl    on;
   ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/my_pem.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/my_key.key;  
   server_name my_server;    

   access_log /var/log/nginx/my_log.access.log;

   ...
}
```

I've tried including www in the server_name and also specifying the explicit url with www for the 301 return.

Everything resulted in invalid url.

I've noticed though that when I'm logged in the application and I change https to http and trigger the request the redirect works. When I'm logged out, the redirect fails and renders the https url without the www.

Then I tried with only server_name like so: return 301 https://$server_name but that didn't work either.

I'd like to have users not worrying about the url they specify. The url is as put together follows www.one.two-three.com

<<< EDIT >>>

This works: http://www.one.two-three.com/some_request

and this doesn't: http://www.one.two-three.com

<<< EDIT >>>

---

<<< EDIT 1 >>>

By typing www.one.two-three.com in the URL line in Chrome/Chromium it redirects to https://www.one.two-three.com.

In Firefox it returns https://one.two-three.com

<<< EDIT 1 >>>

---

Can someone help with this?

Thank you.

Seba

Comment: Clean the browser cache, since the 301 is cachable redirect. You may get buggy ones. Use eg 303 for testing purposes.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use to solve this has 2 parts. First, I set up explicit redirects to go from HTTP to the correct HTTPS URL, as well as from the bare HTTP to "www" HTTPS. Second, this means I may not rely on `$server_name` and so I have a maintainable bit of duplication in my config.

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com example.biz example.us www.example.biz www.example.us;
  return      301     https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen      443;
  server_name example.com example.biz example.us www.example.biz www.example.us;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/com.example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/com.example.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  return      301     https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen      443;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried the setup above and I get this error when reloading the nginx conf: conflicting server name "www.mysite.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

And the browser returns invalid redirect error message.

Comment: Does the subdomain matter in this case? My specific example is www.one.two-three.com where the "one" is subdomain.

Comment: Your first error about the conflicting server name on port 443 was probably caused by copying the server name lists in the wrong server section.

Comment: The domains / sub-domains must be in the right places.

Start with the 3rd server section from my example first - this is your "real" server config and the only place where you are listening on port 443 for `www.one.two-three.com`.

Next setup the 2nd server section (the redirect from port 443) and add `one.two-three.com` there.

Finally, setup the first server section (the redirect from port 80) and add both domain names there.